# How can i can run install script from controller without error

Tags: magento-1.9, install-script

I am running this code and it worked for me but added error in error log

```
$installer = new Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup();
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$installer->getTable('test')};
         CREATE TABLE {$installer->getTable('test')} (
                        ci tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
                        cc char(2) NOT NULL,
                        cn varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (ci)
                        ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
                        ");

$installer->endSetup();
```

but is generating error in error log.

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::__construct(), called in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_9_1_3/app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/controllers/Adminhtml/tesController.php
>   on line 512 and defined  in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_9_1_3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>   on line 127 2017-01-09T12:49:41+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined
>   variable: resourceName  in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_9_1_3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>   on line 130

any idea how remove this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor method for `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` defines a single parameter which is required to create an object instance:

```
public function __construct($resourceName) {...}
```

The `$resourceName` parameter is declared as:

```
@param string $resourceName the setup resource name
```

You can find the setup resource name in the `<global>` section your module's config.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <modulename_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </modulename_write>
    <modulename_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </modulename_read>  
    <namespace_modulename_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Namespace_Modulename</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </namespace_modulename_setup>     
</resources>
```

So, the `$resourceName` parameter should be `'namespace_modulename_setup'` in your case:

```
$installer = new Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup('namespace_modulename_setup');
```

Give it a try. I may be wrong, in which case I'll remove this answer.

Note: module setup code is normally run automatically when a module is first installed or when it's upgraded to a new version. Magento takes care of this for you, so it's not usually necessary to run setup code from within a controller class. The purpose of a controller is to interact with frontend URL requests. They are responsible for loading layouts, doing redirects, sending AJAX responses, etc. Using controllers to execute setup scripts kind of goes against the MVC pattern.

Thanks,
D-man

Answer (score 0):

Setup model is trying to install/upgrade some module in your install script. cannot find a write connection for the resource. It seems issue in defining `config.xml` of your module